# Determine operating system and processor type in C#

Tags: c#, .net, operating-system, wmi

I want to check what type of operating system i use and what kind of processor. this should be check on run time. i tried using

```
System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE")
```

and

```
System.OperatingSystem osInfo2 = System.Environment.OSVersion;
Console.WriteLine(osInfo2.ToString());
```

but it's just the enviroment that VS is running on.
I was told to use WMI to check it but i can't find out how.
can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes WMI is the best way to do this kind of stuff
You can use this to retrieve OS informations :

```
ManagementObjectSearcher objMOS = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM  Win32_OperatingSystem");
```

Answer (score 32):

Retrieving OS info:

```
var wmi =
    new ManagementObjectSearcher( "select * from Win32_OperatingSystem" )
    .Get()
    .Cast<ManagementObject>()
    .First();

OS.Name = ((string)wmi["Caption"]).Trim();
OS.Version = (string)wmi["Version"];
OS.MaxProcessCount = (uint)wmi["MaxNumberOfProcesses"];
OS.MaxProcessRAM = (ulong)wmi["MaxProcessMemorySize"];
OS.Architecture = (string)wmi["OSArchitecture"];
OS.SerialNumber = (string)wmi["SerialNumber"];
OS.Build = ((string)wmi["BuildNumber"]).ToUint();
```

Retrieving CPU info:

```
var cpu =
    new ManagementObjectSearcher( "select * from Win32_Processor" )
    .Get()
    .Cast<ManagementObject>()
    .First();

CPU.ID = (string)cpu["ProcessorId"];
CPU.Socket = (string)cpu["SocketDesignation"];
CPU.Name = (string)cpu["Name"];
CPU.Description = (string)cpu["Caption"];
CPU.AddressWidth = (ushort)cpu["AddressWidth"];
CPU.DataWidth = (ushort)cpu["DataWidth"];
CPU.Architecture = (CPU.CpuArchitecture)(ushort)cpu["Architecture"];
CPU.SpeedMHz = (uint)cpu["MaxClockSpeed"];
CPU.BusSpeedMHz = (uint)cpu["ExtClock"];
CPU.L2Cache = (uint)cpu["L2CacheSize"] * (ulong)1024;
CPU.L3Cache = (uint)cpu["L3CacheSize"] * (ulong)1024;
CPU.Cores = (uint)cpu["NumberOfCores"];
CPU.Threads = (uint)cpu["NumberOfLogicalProcessors"];

CPU.Name =
   CPU.Name
   .Replace( "(TM)", "™" )
   .Replace( "(tm)", "™" )
   .Replace( "(R)", "®" )
   .Replace( "(r)", "®" )
   .Replace( "(C)", "©" )
   .Replace( "(c)", "©" )
   .Replace( "    ", " " )
   .Replace( "  ", " " );
```

Answer (score 2):

To determine the operating system use this code:

```
string OPSystemVersion = Environment.OSVersion.ToString();
```

To determine the CPU name and type first add System.Management reference to your project, then you can use this code:

```
public static string SendBackProcessorName()
        {
            ManagementObjectSearcher mosProcessor = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor");
            string Procname = null;

            foreach (ManagementObject moProcessor in mosProcessor.Get())
            {
                if (moProcessor["name"] != null)
                {
                    Procname = moProcessor["name"].ToString();

                }

            }

            return Procname;
        }
```

Comment: List of version numbers and what version of Windows they correspond to can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724832(v=vs.85).aspx). Windows 7: 6.1, Windows 8: 6.2, Windows 8.1: 6.3, Windows 10: 10.0

Answer (score 0):

Look at the ManagementClass class:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementclass.aspx

```
var mgmt = new ManagementClass("Win32_OperatingSystem");
foreach (ManagementObject mgmtObj in mgmt.GetInstances())
{                
    // Just get first value.
    return mgmtObj[info.Information].ToString().Trim();
}
```