# Testing for virtual memory paging file

Tags: c#, virtual-memory

I'm having a REALLY tough time with something.  I'm using C#, and I want to be able to check whether the virtual memory paging file is currently enabled (or has a maximum size greater than 0, whichever is easier to test).

I haven't found any way to do it (if there is one, *please* tell me!), but I thought I might be able to indirectly accomplish my goal by just checking either how much memory in the paging file my program/process is using or even how much it's *allowed* to use.

So I was using the Process.PagedMemorySize64 and Process.PagedSystemMemorySize64 functions, but they return a positive number even when I have the paging file disabled!  I was told elsewhere that those functions will tell me information about physical memory if a paging file is unavailable.  Well great, because that doesn't help me.

So if anyone knows how to actually get any information about how much memory the current process or whole computer is either using or allowed to use within a paging file, I'd appreciate it!

P.S.: As a related question, does anyone ever get an OutOfMemoryException while trying to write an array into a FileStream in a loop?  I mean I'm not actually *allocating* any memory at that time, and it only happens when I try to write huge files - the small ones write just fine.

Comment: You can use WMI for this. An example how to do it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944779/determine-operating-system-and-processor-type-in-c-sharp, but in your case instead of the table Win32_OperatingSystem you should use Win32_Process (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372(v=vs.85).aspx). I suppose $"SELECT PageFileUsage FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessId={Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id}" should work.

Comment: Maybe Win32_PageFileUsage (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394246(v=vs.85).aspx) is also of use for you. Regarding your PS: no that shouldn't happen. How exactly are you writing arrays to a file, as FileStream only supports byte arrays?

Comment: I am writing a byte array.  And what's with the select statement?  I'm not using a database, just C#.  Is that that Linq stuff or something similar?  Oh, and do I need to include any DLL for any of this stuff?  I'd prefer not to so I can keep my program simpler for distribution, but I'll use a DLL if I must, but I would need to know which one.  Thanks.

Comment: It could be that you would need to add System.Management.dll to your project references, but I don't think you need to distribute it as it's part of the .NET framework. Regarding the select, Microsoft just choose to use a SQL like syntax to query system information using WMI, their is no database involved.

Comment: Well I looked at the example you gave and some stuff I found on MSDN, but it all seemed to do pretty much the same thing as the functions that I mentioned earlier which weren't doing what I need.  That is, unless there's a function I missed or something.  Do you know of a specific one that will tell me anything about page file usage, either globally for the computer or just for the process?  The problem with the string indexer they use is that there's no autocomplete and probably little if any documentation for the specific strings!  But if you could tell me the name of the right one, thanks!

Comment: Sorry I looked at some stuff and decided to rephrase but it wouldn't let me edit again:

I looked at your example and MSDN, but it all seemed to do the same thing as the functions that I mentioned earlier which weren't what I need, unless there's a function I missed.  Do you know of one that will tell me anything about page file usage, either globally for the computer or just for the process?  The problem with the string indexer they use is that there's no autocomplete and the documentation doesn't mention all the specific strings!  But if you could tell me the name of the right one, thanks!